# In which process $\Delta G$ is zero

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

We have to find in which of the process $\Delta G$ is zero .

[image]

I know it zero when there is equilibrium . and according to me every reaction is in equilibrium except the last reaction .
As in them physical conditions are same .

But in my book it is written that on reaction b,c,d,e will have $\Delta G=0$

Comment: You can't just look at whether the values of temperature and pressure are the same on either side. You also must consider the whether those states would coexist under those conditions. For example, water liquid and water vapor are *not* in equilibrium at $0 ^{\circ}\text{C}$ and $1\text{atm}$.

Comment: @Tyberius then how c and d options are in equilibrium

Comment: The info at the bottom says the vapor pressure of water at $27^{\circ} \text{C}$ is $0.04$. From the wikipedia page for [vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure), it is defined as "the pressure exerted by a vapor in thermodynamic equilibrium with its condensed phases (solid or liquid) at a given temperature in a closed system"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your statement "I know it zero when there is equilibrium" is not true. $\Delta \text{G}$ can take any value for a reaction, and the system can be at equilibrium if the concentrations of the reactants and products are at appropriate concentrations for that value. However, $\Delta \text{G} =0$ implies that the equilibrium constant for the reactions or phase change is 1.

Comment: [2  The equilibrium constant](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/thermeq/TE5.html)

Comment: See the link it shows $\Delta G =0$ at equilibrium